# WebServices com C#, fazer de-para

Tags: c#, .net, web-service

Estou precisando criar um WebService para exportar produtos. Criar o WebServico tudo bem, porém dependendo do cliente, vou ter que alterar o nome dos elementos.

Exemplo, elemento do Código do Produto:

**Generico** `<codigo>1</codigo><descricao>Produto</descricao>`

**Cliente A** `<codigoProduto>1</codigoProduto><descProduto>Produto</descProduto>`

**Cliente B** `<codProd>1</codProd><desc>Produto</desc>`

Vou ter que ter 1 (um) WebService para cada tipo de estrutura? Ou existe alguma forma de ter somente o WebService `generico` e receber o WebService do `Cliente A` e do `Cliente B` no WebService `generico`.

Comment: @Marconi é o que eu pensei em fazer. Ter o método padrão e depois os para cada cliente, fazendo o de-para da classe do cliente para a classe padrão. Mas estão querendo fazer algo generico, e até aonde eu sei não teria como fazer isto sem programar, pois tenho que ter a classe pronta para gerar o WebService. A ideia era, aparece o cliente 3, coloca a estrutura num texto e gera o novo metodo, mas acho que isto vai demorar mais do que fazer os metodos conforme demanda.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt. Esclarece uma situação fazer isto para quantos clientes, imagino que não é para muitos.(mais do que 10)
Então, não seria interessante criar perfil (acrescente uma letra no cliente), não seria mais fácil a utilização e manutenção.

Comment: @LuizVichiatto por enquanto é 2 / 3 clientes. Mas a minha maior dúvida é, para gerar o WebService para cada cliente vou ter que ter a classe Produto, ProdutoA, ProdutoB e por ai vai, aonde vou ter um de-para da classe do ProdutoA para a classe Produto, e as implementações sempre seriam em cima da classe Produto, e queria saber se isto é válido, ou se teria algo mais genérico para fazer esta implementação.

Comment: @Marconi, acho que vou seguir a ideia de ter a classe Produto e fazer o de-para, e trabalhar sempre com o Produto. Desta forma imagino que posso separar um pouco as funcionalidades.

Comment: Ok vamos apagar os comentarios? As vezes alguém tem uma resposta pra essa pergunta. Mais creio que ela seja ampla dmais.

Comment: Concordo com o Marconi, essa pergunta, da forma que está formulado, está muito ampla, tanto que tem uma enxurrada de comentários. Tente editar a perguntar restringindo um pouco mais o seu escopo.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar pergunta editada, será que ficou mais clara?

Comment: @Marconi pergunta editada, será que ficou mais clara?

Comment: @marlon.tiedt ficou bem melhor sim. Esses dias fiz uma compra na Kanui e outra na Saraiva ambas com a mesma transportadora. No link do WebService de rastreio deles era trato um para a kanui e outro para a Saraiva. Creio eu também ser a melhor opção;

Answer (score 2):

utilize o polimorfismo, ou, crie uma classe genérica que possa ser configurada de acordo com o cliente.

se houver apenas 2 ou 3 modelos, utilizaria o polimorfismo, se houver a necessidade de acrescentar mais outros futuramente, utilizaria apenas uma classe genérica que teria toda esse configuração feita em banco de dados.

Ex: Polimorfismo

```
public class Produto
{
    public virtual string GetXml()
    {
        return "<codigo>1</codigo><descricao>Produto</descricao>";
    }
}

public class ProdutoClienteA : Produto
{
    public override string GetXml()
    {
        return "<codigoProduto>1</codigoProduto><descProduto>Produto</descProduto>";
    }
}

public class WebService
{
    public string GetProduto(string cliente)
    {
        Produto obj;
        if (cliente=="A")
        {
            obj = new ProdutoClienteA();
        }
        else
        {
            obj = new Produto();
        }

        return obj.GetXml();
    }
}
```

Lembrando que é apenas um exemplo simples, há vários outros recursos para implementar, inclusive o serialization, que iria gerar o xml do objeto automaticamente.

de outra forma, teria uma tabela de relacionamento dos campos de produtos, clientes, e valores que devem ser atribuidos, ex.

Campo, Cliente, novoCampo
codigo, A, codigoProduto
codigo, B, codProd

aí o cliente entraria com toda a configuração que ele precisar, e quando for retornar no webservice, apenas lê essa tabela e substitui o campo pelo valor correto. Dessa forma se surgir um novo cliente com uma configuração totalmente diferente, não é necessário nenhuma intervenção no programa.

Answer (score 0):

Na maioria das vezes, há uma alternativa estática para a questão, basta renegociar o contrato da API com o consumidor.

Quando isso não é possível, você pode optar por estruturas estáticas com dados dinâmicos (Listas com objetos pre-definidos que possuem chave-valor) ou mesmo dicionários.

Outra alternativa e aí endereça o seu cenário é usar uma API totalmente dinâmica ([Link para o post 'Dynamic action return'](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/02/dynamic-action-return-web-api-2-1/)), nesse caso WebAPI é o melhor cenário. Você vai precisar de algum conhecimento prévio de HTTP (pois você vai precisar reproduzir o request para gerar um response compatível), o que não é nada demais. Abaixo segue o link para o último caso.